# Business Objects/SQL Server Orphaned Queries

Tags: sql-server, business-objects

I'm a SQL Server DBA working on a project that is using SAP Business Objects 4.1 to deliver reports from a SQL Server 2008R2 database. This is my first encounter with BO, and my involvement in it on this project has only been to support the DB operations.

I've noticed that when users start running a report, but cancel it, the query keeps running to completion. Is there any way for BO to know to kill these queries if the subscriber/client is no longer active?

Also, I've noticed that there are lots of little sub-queries running throughout the day that don't seem to be initiated by a particular report request, like "SELECT Distinct StoreName FROM vwStores". I'm guessing that these are some sort of maintenance/data refresh operations used to update the BO Universe, but that's a wild shot in the dark. If I'm correct, is there any way to control/schedule when these take place? Otherwise, what are these?

Comment: [Bad news on the cancel](http://scn.sap.com/thread/1735615) With regards to the small queries, they aren't maintenance they are queries to Populate List of values users use to select parameters for reports, or they could be values coming back as users attempt to design develop new reports.  In other words, this will likely become the new standard for you.

Comment: I am not sure about the cancelling but I believe the random quiries you are seeing are from the crawler that collects metadata. https://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw73/helpdata/en/46/5d5040b48a6913e10000000a1550b0/content.htm

Answer (score 1):

The cancel issue has been addressed in recent support packs.  See SAP Note [1605937](https://service.sap.com/sap/support/notes/1605937).

The SELECT DISTINCT issue is caused by universe indexing, which can (luckily) be turned off in the CMC.  The SAP note [1711167](https://service.sap.com/sap/support/notes/1711167) explains how in detail. You need to find the "Platform Search Application" and change the scope of indexing to "Platform metadata". Not sure why "Full Content" is the default value, except perhaps to cause headaches for DBAs?